# php - Iterate through array and order by dependencies

Tags: php, dependencies

I was wondering if there is a known class/functions or any tutorials out there that can help in ordering an array by its dependency (stored as there value of the key pair).

i.e. (please note these are not actual dependancies)

```
Array
(
    [blueimp-canvas-to-blob] => Array
        (
        )

    [blueimp-load-image] => Array
        (
            [0] => jquery
        )

    [blueimp-tmpl] => Array
        (
            [0] => jquery
            [1] => blueimp-load-image
        )

    [jquery] => Array
        (
        )

    [blueimp-file-upload] => Array
        (
            [0] => jquery
            [1] => blueimp-tmpl
            [2] => blueimp-load-image
            [3] => blueimp-canvas-to-blob
        )

)
```

would be ordered as:

```
Array
(
    [blueimp-canvas-to-blob] => Array
        (
        )

    [jquery] => Array
        (
        )

    [blueimp-load-image] => Array
        (
            [0] => jquery
        )

    [blueimp-tmpl] => Array
        (
            [0] => jquery
            [1] => blueimp-load-image
        )

    [blueimp-file-upload] => Array
        (
            [0] => jquery
            [1] => blueimp-tmpl
            [2] => blueimp-load-image
            [3] => blueimp-canvas-to-blob
        )

)
```

any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to figure this out (i think):

```
private function orderItems(){
    while( ! empty( $this->order ) ) {
        $item = array_splice( $this->order, 0, 1 );
        $dependencies = end( $item );
        $name = key( $item );
        if( empty( $dependencies ) ) {
            $this->ordered[$name] = $dependencies;
        } else {
            $satisafied = true;
            foreach( $dependencies as $dependency ) {
                if( isset( $this->order[$dependency] ) ) $satisafied = false;
            }
            if( $satisafied ) {
                $this->ordered[$name] = $dependencies;
            } else {
                $this->order = $this->order + $item;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

here if anyone else wants something simular